# Можно ли кастомизировать QTabWidget определенным образом?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qtabwidget

У меня появилась идея. Я понимаю, что она трудновыполнимая, но не знаю насколько. 
Мне нужно изменить внешний вид виджета `QTabWidget` следующим образом:

1. В заголовки вкладок поместить изображения(обычные, без особых
   характеристик)
2. Закруглить все возможные края всех вкладок
3. Убрать рамку(обводку)
4. Задать цвета активной и неактивной вкладок
5. Перевернуть виджет так, как я нарисовал на картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Я пытался убрать рамку вкладок в таблице стиля, но это не работает так, как с другими виджетами. Пытался что-то загуглить, но не нашел ничего полезного. Теперь мне кажется, что я слишком много хочу. Можно ли реализовать задуманное? Если можно, пожалуйста, подскажите как

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        tab = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        tab.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('1'), 'Вкладка 1')
        tab.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('2'), 'Вкладка 2')
        tab.setCurrentIndex(0)

        tab.setStyleSheet('''border-style: hidden;
                             border-width: 2px;
                             border-radius: 10px;''')

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(tab)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('QTabWidget')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Много задавать вопросов (в одном посте) не слишком здорово. Реализовать можно практический все, только торопится не надо.

Мне увиделась ваша задача так. Только подобрать цвета и сделать закругления попробуйте сразу самостоятельно. Почитайте посты с ключевыми словами `Style Sheet`.

Вы также можете увидит другую реализацию вашей идеи [Pyqt 5 изменение текущий элемент в QListWidget](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089514/pyqt-5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-qlistwidget/1089535#1089535)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Color(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Color, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)


class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        s.transpose()
        return s

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.save()

            s = opt.rect.size()
            s.transpose()
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
            opt.rect = r

            c = self.tabRect(i).center()
            painter.translate(c)
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(-c)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt);
            painter.restore()


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(self))
        self.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(800, 400)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)         # !!!    

        self.tabs = TabWidget()                                                  # QtWidgets.QTabWidget()

        self.tabs.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)                      #
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.setMovable(True)
        self.tabs.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('1', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter), 
                QIcon('images/info.ico'), '')                                    # 'Вкладка 1'

        self.tabs.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('2'), QIcon('head3.png'), '')          # , 'Вкладка 2'
        self.tabs.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))

        for n, color in enumerate(['red','green','blue','yellow']):
            self.tabs.addTab( Color(color), color)

        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(0)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(self.tabs)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)


qss = '''
QTabBar {
    background: #c3c3c3;          
}
QTabBar::tab {
    background: rgb(34, 137, 163);
    color: white;
}
QTabBar::tab:selected {
    background-color: rgb(48, 199, 184,);
    color: #000000;
}
QLabel {
    background-color: #23272a;
    font-size: 22px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    color: white;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                             # +
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('QTabWidget')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @MAXIM045 я добавил несколько новых строк в описание ответа, перечитайте его.

Comment: @MAXIM045 извини, мне тяжело додумывать что и где не так. Если есть проблема, формируйте минимальный пример с этой проблемой, говори что надо сделать и показывай визуально как это должно выглядеть в результате. И конечно говорите и показывайте что вы пытались сделать и что вышло не так.