# Настроить цвет изменённой вкладки QTabWidget

Tags: python, pyqt, qss, qtabwidget, qtabbar

Есть изменённый `QTabWidget`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изменён с помощью доп класса

```
class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        s.transpose()
        return s

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()


        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.save()

            s = opt.rect.size()
            s.transpose()
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
            opt.rect = r

            c = self.tabRect(i).center()
            painter.translate(c)
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(-c)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)

            painter.restore()
```

---

Изменение цвета через `StyleSheet` даёт результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сделать нормальное изменение цвета. Реализовывал с помощью вот этого решения(отрисовка прямоугольника поверх вкладок) https://progi.pro/izmenenie-cveta-vkladki-qtabwidget-10554526, но такая реализация мне не понравилась.

За отрисовку повернутых вкладок отвечает строчка:

```
painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
```

Значит ли это, что в `QtWidgets.QStyle` заложены цвета по умолчанию для вкладок (нажатие, активная, наведение)?

Можно ли их изменить напрямую в `QStyle`, чтобы всё отрисовывалось как надо?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> enum QStyle::ControlElement
>
> Это перечисление представляет собой элемент управления.
> Элемент управления - это часть виджета, которая выполняет какое-либо действие
> или отображает информацию для пользователя.
> Больше ... https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#ControlElement-enum
>
> ...
> QStyle::CE_TabBarTabShape - Форма вкладки на панели вкладок.
> QStyle::CE_TabBarTabLabel - Ярлык на вкладке
> ...

Также вы можете посмотреть другую реализацию с использованием таблицы стилей:
[Можно ли кастомизировать QTabWidget определенным образом?(PyQt 5, Python 3)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1092931/%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-qtabwidget-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bcpyqt-5-python-3)

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets


class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def __init__(self, colors, parent=None):
        super(TabBar, self).__init__(parent)
        self.mColors = colors

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            if opt.text in self.mColors:
                opt.palette.setColor(
                    QtGui.QPalette.Button, self.mColors[opt.text]
                )
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TabWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        d = {
            "All":        QtGui.QColor("yellow"),
            "purchase":   QtGui.QColor("#87ceeb"),
            "POS Sales":  QtGui.QColor("#90EE90"),
            "Cash Sales": QtGui.QColor("pink"),
            "invoice":    QtGui.QColor("#800080"),
        }
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(d))

        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "All")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "purchase")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "POS Sales")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "Cash Sales")
        self.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel(), "invoice")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    # Внимание!  работает только в том случае, если вы используете стиль fusion, ... 
    app.setStyle("fusion")                                                     # !!!
    
    w = TabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @SNick Ваш ответ помог, но возник ещё вопрос. Почему это работает только при стиле fusion? Такое изменение палитры  я пробовал, но оно естественно не работало,т.к. не было стиля fusion

Comment: @Skeggi Цвета палитры, по сути, являются справочными. 
Некоторые виджеты не имеют определенной роли для своего поведения при рисовании, и стиль, 
который решает, какую роль использовать и как, и это в случае QTabWidget. 
В Linux стандартным стилем обычно является "Fusion", который использует роль кнопки 
для рисования фона виджета вкладки, но когда этот фон окрашивается, 
вместо этого используется градиент, основанный на этом цвете. 
Этот стиль виджета должен быть одинаковым как в Windows, так и в Linux.

Comment: @Skeggi Также смотрите в этом Qt FAQ 
https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_project_org_faq#Why_does_nothing_happen_when_I_set_the_palette_background_color_on_a_QPushButton_in_some_styles.3F