# Как закруглить края взаимосвязанных виджетов QListWidget и QStackedWidget или второй вариант с QTabWidget?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qss, qtabwidget

Код ниже имитирует панель вкладок, создавая взаимосвязанные `QListWidget` и `QStackedWidget`. Сейчас это выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно закруглить края каждой 'вкладки'. Это очень важно, и без этого я не могу двигаться дальше. Конечный результат должен выглядеть так(первая вкладка - 6 закругленных углов, вторая вкладка - 8 закругленных углов):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне показалось, что самое сложное - сделать внутренние(впуклые) углы, которые я  отметил на схеме восклицательными знаками. Сейчас я придумал одну вещь, которая должна помочь сделать это немного проще. Внутренние углы активной вкладки можно нарисовать на изображении, находящемся на неактивной вкладке. Таким образом, изображение вкладки номер 2, когда вкладка номер 1 будет являться активной, будет выглядеть так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.к. активной счтается вкладка номер 1, она будет находиться выше, значит, своим внутренним углом будет перекрывать вторую вкладку. Поэтому на изображении выше правый верхний угол второй вкладки перекрыт правым нижним углом первой вкладки.

Так же я сделал и для первой вкладки, на случай, когда она станет неактивной:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но этого не хватает. Когда вторая вкладка становится активной, у нее появляется два внутренних угла. На картинке выше изображен только правый верхний. Правый нижний угол выйдет за пределы обоих элементов `QListWidget`. Я предполагаю, что можно будет создавать третий элемент в `QListWidget`, который будет состоять только из одного уголка второй активной вкладки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**^^^ Надпись, чтобы обратить внимание на этот уголок, можно не заметить:)**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что делать с углами основного тела вкладки(`QStackedWidget`) я тоже не знаю. Когда активной будет первая вкладка, нужно закруглять только три угла(левый нижний, правый верхний, правый нижний). Когда активной будет вторая вкладка, нужно закруглять все углы.

Вот все изображения для вкладок, которые могут пригодиться(радиус всех скруглений - 10px):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю, как можно сделать все это. Не понимаю, как можно будет поменять картинку на вкладке, когда она станет активной/неактивной. Не знаю, как можно будет добавить некликабельный уголок в `QListWidget`. Может быть, все, что я расписал выше, не будет работать? Может быть, есть способ проще? Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно скруглить края этих 'вкладок'?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class LeftTabWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LeftTabWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setMinimumSize(500, 300)

        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button')
        layout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout1.addWidget(btn)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0) 
        self.listWidget.setViewMode(QtWidgets.QListView.IconMode)
        self.listWidget.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(60, 60))               
        self.listWidget.setMovement(QtWidgets.QListView.Static)
        self.listWidget.setMaximumWidth(60)
        self.listWidget.setMinimumWidth(60)
        self.listWidget.setSpacing(0)  

        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 1', self)
        label1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label1.setStyleSheet('background: #7189DB;')
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label1)

        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Страница 2', self)
        label2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        label2.setStyleSheet('background: #45507E;')
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(label2)

        self.createIcons()
        self.listWidget.setCurrentRow(0)

        layout2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(spacing=0) 
        layout2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout2.addWidget(self.listWidget)              
        layout2.addWidget(self.stackedWidget, 1)
        layout1.addLayout(layout2)

    def createIcons(self):
        configButton = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
        configButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('btn1.png'))
        configButton.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        configButton.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)

        updateButton = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem(self.listWidget)
        updateButton.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('btn2.png'))
        updateButton.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        updateButton.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsSelectable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        self.listWidget.currentItemChanged.connect(self.changePage)

    def changePage(self, current, previous):
        if not current:
            current = previous
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(self.listWidget.row(current))


Stylesheet = '''
QListWidget {
    border: none;   
}

QListWidget::item {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #3b4155;
}

QListWidget::item:selected {
    background-color: #7189DB;
}
QListWidget::item:!selected {
    background-color: #7189DB;
}

QLabel {  
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    font: 21pt;
}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    w = LeftTabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**--- ВТОРОЙ ВАРИАНТ С `QTabWidget` ---**

Раньше я пытался использовать `QTabWidget`. Причиной, по которой я отказался от данного виджета, является странное поведение изображения, которое я пытался поместить в область заголовка вкладки. Почему-то картинка не попадает в центр этой области, а располагается ближе к левому краю виджета. Эту проблему подробнее я расписал тут - [Как убрать лишние края области заголовка вкладки виджета QTabWidget?(PyQt 5, Python 3)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1093109/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%88%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-qtabwidgetpyqt-5-pyt)

В комментариях со мной поделились ссылкой - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713741/qtabwidget-tab-icons-not-in-the-center. Тут описывается способ поправить ситуацию, который, к сожалению, мне не помог. Следуя совету из этой ссылки, я изменил тот код с `QTabWidget`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui

class Color(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Color, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)

class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        s.transpose()
        return s

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.save()

            s = opt.rect.size()
            s.transpose()
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
            opt.rect = r

            c = self.tabRect(i).center()
            painter.translate(c)
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(-c)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)
            painter.restore()

class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(self))
        self.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.resize(250, 300)

        self.tabs = TabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        self.tabs.addTab(Color('#7189DB'), QtGui.QIcon('play.png'), '')
        self.tabs.addTab(Color('#7189DB'), 'Вкладка 2')
        self.tabs.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(40, 40))


        qss = '''QTabBar::tab:hover {
                     background-color: #212121;
                 }

                 QTabBar::tab:selected{
                     background-color: #313131;
                 }
                 QTabBar::tab {
                     background-color: #111111; 
                     height:70px;
                     width: 70px;
                     border: none;
                     margin: 0px;
                     padding-top: -15px;
                     padding-bottom: 15px
                     padding-right: 0px;
                     padding-left: 0px;
                 }'''


        self.tabs.setStyleSheet(qss)

        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(0)

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(self.tabs)

    def closeTab(self, index):
        tab = self.tabs.widget(index)
        tab.deleteLater()
        self.tabs.removeTab(index)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

В таблице стиля есть такие строки:

```
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px;
```

Я пытался задать данным параметрам разные значения, но все приводили к одному и тому же результату:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несмотря на это, я пытался закруглить края виджета, изменив таблицу стиля следующим образом:

```
qss = '''QTabBar::tab:hover {
             background-color: #212121;
         }

         QTabBar::tab:selected{
             background-color: #313131;
         }
         QTabBar::tab {
             background-color: #111111; 
             height:70px;
             width: 70px;
             border: none;
             margin: 0px;
             padding-top: -15px;
             padding-bottom: 15px
             padding-right: 15px;
             padding-left: 15px;
         }
         QTabBar::pane {
             border-style: hidden;
             border-width: 2px;
             border-radius: 10px;                     
         }'''
```

Ничего не произошло

Comment: Вы принципиально не используете QTabWidget? Его тоже можно стилизовать, например вот так https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38369015/customuzing-qtabwidget-with-style-sheets

Comment: Вот оф.док https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: Да. Изначально я планировал настроить необходимые характеристики у `QTabWidget`, но там появляются проблемы с добавлением изображения в область заголовка вкладки. Картинка не хочет попадать в центр этой области. Я задавал уже здесь вопрос по этому поводу

Comment: Вот это? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47713741/qtabwidget-tab-icons-not-in-the-center

Comment: Сейчас буду смотреть. Спасибо большое

Comment: Почему-то появляется та же проблема. Я поставил себе таблицу стиля из ответа, но картинку тянет к левой границе вкладки

Comment: Поиграйтесь с padding-left и padding-right

Comment: Все значения, которые я пытался присвоить этим пунктам приводили к тому, что рамка снизу и сверху становилась очень маленькой, а по краям расширялась в раза два. Даже если значение равно 0. Возможно не так применял. Я уже очень сильно запутался. Никогда не думал, что закруглить края будет такой проблемой

Comment: Я бы вообще очень хотел, чтобы этой рамки не было. Она мне абсолютно не нужна и все усложняет

Comment: `Добавьте` пожалуйста в пояснение вопроса второй пример с использованием `QTabWidget`.

Comment: @S.Nick, прошу прощения, что так долго. Я пытался понятнее сформулировать мысли. Дополнил вопрос. Скажите, пожалуйста, если чего-то не хватает. И еще, если вы не видели, пожалуйста, посмотрите, что я написал под прошлым вопросом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я конечно не уверен, что мои фантазии оптимальны, но оно как бы работает.
За основу взят ВТОРОЙ ВАРИАНТ С `QTabWidget`, т.к. 
в таблице стилей `QTabBar` есть - `:first` и `:last`.

Обратите внимание, как вставляются изображения:

```
border-image: url(btn72.png) repeat;
```

Картинки, которые я использовал, надо нарисовать поаккуратнее.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Color(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, color, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Color, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        palette = self.palette()
        palette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtGui.QColor(color))
        self.setPalette(palette)


class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        s.transpose()
        return s

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()
        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.save()
            s = opt.rect.size()
            s.transpose()
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
            opt.rect = r
            c = self.tabRect(i).center()
            painter.translate(c)
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(-c)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt);
            painter.restore()


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(self))
        self.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setFixedSize(800, 400)

        self.current_index = 1                                                   # +++

        self.tabs = TabWidget()                                  
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.tabsCurrentChanged)                # +++->(int index)

        self.tabs.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)                      
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)
        #self.tabs.setMovable(True)

        self.tabs.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('1', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter), '') # 'Вкладка first'
        self.tabs.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('1', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter), '') # 'Вкладка 1'
        self.tabs.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('2', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter), '') # 'Вкладка 2'
        self.tabs.addTab(QtWidgets.QLabel('2', alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter), '') # 'Вкладка last'                               #  'Вкладка last'

        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(self.current_index)                            # + self.current_index

        box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        box.addWidget(self.tabs)
        box.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
    def tabsCurrentChanged(self, index): 
        #print(f'def tabsCurrentChanged(self, index): {index} - {self.current_index}')
        if index == 0 or index == 3:
            self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(self.current_index)

        if index == 1:  
            self.tabs.setStyleSheet('''
                QTabBar::tab:first:!selected  {
                    border-image: url(btn72.png) repeat;         
                } 
                QTabBar::tab:!selected {
                    border-image: url(btn6.png) repeat;          
                } 
                QTabBar::tab:last:!selected  {
                    border-image: url(btn82.png) repeat;
                } 
            ''')
            self.current_index = index  

        if index == 2:                         
            self.tabs.setStyleSheet('''
                QTabBar::tab:first:!selected  {
                    border-image: url(btn71.png) repeat;
                }  
                QTabBar::tab:last:!selected  {
                    border-image: url(btn81.png) repeat;
                }  
                QTabBar::tab:!selected {
                    border-image: url(btn41.png) repeat; 
                }
            ''')
            self.current_index = index
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       


qss = '''
QTabBar {
    background-color: #fff;    
}

QTabBar::tab {
    background: rgb(34, 137, 163);
    color: white;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    color: #ff0000;
    background-color: green;
    border-image: url(btn2.png);
    border-top-left-radius: 25px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;  
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;    
}

QTabBar::tab:!selected {
    background-color: yellow;    
    border-image: url(btn5.png) repeat;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px; 
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px; 
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

/* ********* first ********************** */
QTabBar::tab:first:!selected  {
    border-image: url(btn72.png) repeat;
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
} 
QTabBar::tab:first:selected  {
    border-image: url(btn71.png) repeat;       
    margin-top: 60px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
} 

/* ********* last *********************** */
QTabBar::tab:last:!selected  {
    border-image: url(btn82.png) repeat;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
} 
QTabBar::tab:last:selected  {
    border-image: url(btn81.png) repeat; 
    margin-bottom: 60px;
    width: 80px;
    height: 20px;
} 

QWidget>QLabel {                        /* ! QWidget>QLabel */
    margin: 0px;
    color: white;
    font: 21pt;
    background: #7189DB;
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px; 
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}

QWidget {
    background-color: #fff;

}
'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(qss)                             # +
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle('QTabWidget')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**btn2.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**btn41.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**btn5.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**btn6.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**btn71.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**btn72.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**btn81.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**btn82.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не знаю, чтобы я делал без вашего ответа :) Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Если вам вдруг будет интересно, я оставил еще один способ добиться закругленных вкладок. Мне хотелось проверить, будет ли функционировать то, что я себе представил. Работает не очень быстро, но пользоваться можно. Плюс этого способа в том, что он вышел на 110 строк кода :)

Answer (score 1):

Еще один способ.

Тут я использую две кнопки и контейнер со свойством `background-color`.

---

**1.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**1sleep.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**2sleep.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**corner.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**corner1.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**corner2.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**nothing.png** - пустая картинка 10px*10px. Нужна, чтобы один из контейнеров не менял размер

**вот она>**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]**<**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.corner = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.corner.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('corner.png'))
        self.corner.setFixedHeight(10)

        self.nothing = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.nothing.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('nothing.png'))
        self.nothing.setFixedSize(10, 10)

        self.corner1 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.corner1.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('corner1.png'))
        self.corner1.setFixedSize(50, 10)

        self.corner2 = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.corner2.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap('corner2.png'))
        self.corner2.setFixedSize(50, 10)

        self.corner_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.corner_box.addWidget(self.corner, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)
        self.corner_box.addWidget(self.nothing, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.corner.hide()

        self.current_index = 1

        main_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Main Box')
        main_box.addWidget(btn)

        box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(spacing = 0)
        main_box.addLayout(box1)

        self.box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel('Page 1', alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.btn1 = self.make_btn('1.png')
        self.btn1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.remake_btn(1))
        self.btn2 = self.make_btn('2sleep.png')
        self.btn2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.remake_btn(2))
        self.box2.addWidget(self.btn1)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.btn2)
        self.box2.addWidget(self.corner1)
        self.corner1.hide()
        self.box2.addWidget(self.corner2)

        self.box2.addStretch(1)

        box1.addLayout(self.box2)

        self.container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.container.setStyleSheet(qss_box)
        self.container.setFixedWidth(200)
        self.container.setMinimumHeight(150)
        box1.addWidget(self.container)
        self.box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.container)
        self.box3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 20)

        self.box3.addLayout(self.corner_box)
        self.box3.addWidget(self.label)

    def make_btn(self, picture):
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        btn.setFixedSize(50, 50)
        btn.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(picture))
        btn.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(50, 50))
        btn.setStyleSheet(qss_btn)
        return btn

    def remake_btn(self, index):
        if (index == 1) and (self.current_index != 1):
            self.corner.hide()
            self.corner1.hide()
            self.corner2.show()
            self.btn1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('1'))
            self.btn2.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('2sleep'))
            self.label.setText('Page 1')
            self.current_index = 1

        if (index == 2) and (self.current_index != 2):
            self.corner.show()
            self.corner2.hide()
            self.corner1.show()
            self.btn2.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('1'))
            self.btn1.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('1sleep'))
            self.label.setText('Page 2')
            self.current_index = 2


qss_btn = '''QPushButton {
                 border: none;
                 margin: 0px;
                 padding: 0px;
             }'''

qss_box = '''QWidget {
                 background-color: #7189DB;
                 border-top-right-radius: 10px;
                 border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
                 border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
             }'''


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```