# Как создавать несколько виджетов друг на друге в QT Designer?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, pyside2, qstackedwidget

Как создать несколько фреймов друг на друге в `QT Designer` (я использую pyside для создания своего Python-приложения), чтобы при нажатии на кнопки слева (на скриншоте), текущий фрейм скрывался и показывался другой (в зависимости от нажатой кнопки)?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте в вопрос код, сгенерированный QtDesigner

Comment: Это ж обычные табы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может вам понравится такой вариант:

**main.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from ui_main import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_functions import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # TOGGLE/BURGUER MENU
        self.ui.Btn_Toggle.clicked.connect(lambda: UIFunctions.toggleMenu(self, 250, True))

        # PAGE 1
        self.ui.btn_page_1.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_1))

        # PAGE 2
        self.ui.btn_page_2.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_2))

        # PAGE 3
        self.ui.btn_page_3.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.ui.stackedWidget.setCurrentWidget(self.ui.page_3))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**ui_functions.py**

```
from main import *

class UIFunctions(MainWindow):

    def toggleMenu(self, maxWidth, enable):
        if enable:

            # GET WIDTH
            width = self.ui.frame_left_menu.width()
            maxExtend = maxWidth
            standard = 70

            # SET MAX WIDTH
            if width == 70:
                widthExtended = maxExtend
            else:
                widthExtended = standard

            # ANIMATION
            self.animation = QPropertyAnimation(self.ui.frame_left_menu, b"minimumWidth")
            self.animation.setDuration(400)
            self.animation.setStartValue(width)
            self.animation.setEndValue(widthExtended)
            self.animation.setEasingCurve(QtCore.QEasingCurve.InOutQuart)
            self.animation.start()
```

**ui_main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1000, 500)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1000, 500))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.Top_Bar = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Top_Bar.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 40))
        self.Top_Bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")
        self.Top_Bar.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Top_Bar.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Top_Bar.setObjectName("Top_Bar")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Top_Bar)
        self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.frame_toggle = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Top_Bar)
        self.frame_toggle.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 40))
        self.frame_toggle.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);")
        self.frame_toggle.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_toggle.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_toggle.setObjectName("frame_toggle")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_toggle)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.Btn_Toggle = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_toggle)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.Btn_Toggle.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.Btn_Toggle.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.Btn_Toggle.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border: 0px solid;")
        self.Btn_Toggle.setObjectName("Btn_Toggle")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.Btn_Toggle)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_toggle)
        self.frame_top = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Top_Bar)
        self.frame_top.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_top.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top.setObjectName("frame_top")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_top)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Top_Bar)
        self.Content = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        self.Content.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.Content.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.Content.setObjectName("Content")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.Content)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setSpacing(0)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.frame_left_menu = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_left_menu.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 0))
        self.frame_left_menu.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(70, 16777215))
        self.frame_left_menu.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);")
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_left_menu.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_left_menu.setObjectName("frame_left_menu")
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.frame_top_menus = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_top_menus.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_top_menus.setObjectName("frame_top_menus")
        self.verticalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setSpacing(0)
        self.verticalLayout_4.setObjectName("verticalLayout_4")
        self.btn_page_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_1.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_1.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_1.setObjectName("btn_page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_1)
        self.btn_page_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_2.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_2.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_2.setObjectName("btn_page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_2)
        self.btn_page_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_top_menus)
        self.btn_page_3.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        self.btn_page_3.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {\n"
"    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);\n"
"    border: 0px solid;\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);\n"
"}")
        self.btn_page_3.setObjectName("btn_page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_4.addWidget(self.btn_page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.frame_top_menus, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_left_menu)
        self.frame_pages = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.Content)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_pages.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_pages.setObjectName("frame_pages")
        self.verticalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout_5.setObjectName("verticalLayout_5")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_1.setObjectName("page_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_1)
        self.verticalLayout_7.setObjectName("verticalLayout_7")
        self.label_1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_1)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_1.setFont(font)
        self.label_1.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF;")
        self.label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_1.setObjectName("label_1")
        self.verticalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_1)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_1)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_2)
        self.verticalLayout_6.setObjectName("verticalLayout_6")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_2)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF;")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.verticalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_8.setObjectName("verticalLayout_8")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.page_3)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: #FFF;")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout_8.addWidget(self.label)
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        self.verticalLayout_5.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_pages)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.Content)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Btn_Toggle.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TOGGLE"))
        self.btn_page_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 1"))
        self.btn_page_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 2"))
        self.btn_page_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Page 3"))
        self.label_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PAGE 1"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PAGE 2"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PAGE 3"))
```

**ui_main.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>500</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>1000</width>
    <height>500</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(45, 45, 45);</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="Top_Bar">
      <property name="maximumSize">
       <size>
        <width>16777215</width>
        <height>40</height>
       </size>
      </property>
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_toggle">
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>70</width>
           <height>40</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item>
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="Btn_Toggle">
            <property name="sizePolicy">
             <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
              <horstretch>0</horstretch>
              <verstretch>0</verstretch>
             </sizepolicy>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
border: 0px solid;</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>TOGGLE</string>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_top">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="Content">
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout_2">
       <property name="spacing">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="leftMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="topMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="rightMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="bottomMargin">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_left_menu">
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>70</width>
           <height>0</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="maximumSize">
          <size>
           <width>70</width>
           <height>16777215</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="styleSheet">
          <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);</string>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_3">
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item alignment="Qt::AlignTop">
           <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_top_menus">
            <property name="frameShape">
             <enum>QFrame::NoFrame</enum>
            </property>
            <property name="frameShadow">
             <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
            </property>
            <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_4">
             <property name="spacing">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="leftMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="topMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="rightMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <property name="bottomMargin">
              <number>0</number>
             </property>
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_page_1">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>0</width>
                 <height>40</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
    border: 0px solid;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);
}</string>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>Page 1</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_page_2">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>0</width>
                 <height>40</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
    border: 0px solid;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);
}</string>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>Page 2</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item>
              <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_page_3">
               <property name="minimumSize">
                <size>
                 <width>0</width>
                 <height>40</height>
                </size>
               </property>
               <property name="styleSheet">
                <string notr="true">QPushButton {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgb(35, 35, 35);
    border: 0px solid;
}
QPushButton:hover {
    background-color: rgb(85, 170, 255);
}</string>
               </property>
               <property name="text">
                <string>Page 3</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
       <item>
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_pages">
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_5">
          <item>
           <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
            <property name="currentIndex">
             <number>0</number>
            </property>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="page_1">
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_7">
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label_1">
                <property name="font">
                 <font>
                  <pointsize>40</pointsize>
                 </font>
                </property>
                <property name="styleSheet">
                 <string notr="true">color: #FFF;</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>PAGE 1</string>
                </property>
                <property name="alignment">
                 <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="page_2">
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_6">
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
                <property name="font">
                 <font>
                  <pointsize>40</pointsize>
                 </font>
                </property>
                <property name="styleSheet">
                 <string notr="true">color: #FFF;</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>PAGE 2</string>
                </property>
                <property name="alignment">
                 <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
            <widget class="QWidget" name="page_3">
             <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_8">
              <item>
               <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
                <property name="font">
                 <font>
                  <pointsize>40</pointsize>
                 </font>
                </property>
                <property name="styleSheet">
                 <string notr="true">color: #FFF;</string>
                </property>
                <property name="text">
                 <string>PAGE 3</string>
                </property>
                <property name="alignment">
                 <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
                </property>
               </widget>
              </item>
             </layout>
            </widget>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это потрясающе! Я, если честно, не очень поял, что делает кнопка `Toggle`, но всё равно - бесконечное спасибо!

Comment: @Starter  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: я сделал это! =)

Comment: Кажется, у меня есть ещё один вопрос. В модуле `UI-functions.py` вы прописали какую-то анимацию и код получения и установки ширины фрейма. Зачем это нужно? Кажется, код кнопок, отвечающих за переключение виджетов, находится в `main.py`.

Comment: @Starter то, что вы уточняете, не имеет отношение к вашему заданному основному вопросу. Если у вас возникают другие вопросы - задайте их, сформировав новый вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Класс `QStackedWidget` предоставляет стек виджетов, где одновременно виден только один виджет.
Читаем здесь https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html

1. `stacked_ui.ui`

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>518</width>
    <height>277</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
   <item row="0" column="0">
    <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
     <item>
      <widget class="QListWidget" name="listWidget">
       <property name="maximumSize">
        <size>
         <width>100</width>
         <height>16777215</height>
        </size>
       </property>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Item  1</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Item 2</string>
        </property>
       </item>
       <item>
        <property name="text">
         <string>Item 3</string>
        </property>
       </item>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item>
      <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
       <widget class="QWidget" name="page">
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background:blue;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="page_2">
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background:red;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="page_3">
        <property name="styleSheet">
         <string notr="true">background:yellow;</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>listWidget</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. `pyuic5 stacked_ui.ui -o stacked_ui.py -x`

---

3. `main.py`

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *

#from stacked_ui import Ui_Form
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(518, 277)
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Form)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(Form)
        self.listWidget.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(100, 16777215))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(Form)
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.page = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page.setStyleSheet("background:blue;")
        self.page.setObjectName("page")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page)
        self.page_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_2.setStyleSheet("background:red;")
        self.page_2.setObjectName("page_2")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_2)
        self.page_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.page_3.setStyleSheet("background:yellow;")
        self.page_3.setObjectName("page_3")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.page_3)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.stackedWidget)
        self.gridLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Item  1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Item 2"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "Item 3"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)



class StackedExample(QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(StackedExample, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        self.listWidget.currentRowChanged.connect(self.display)

    def display(self, row):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = StackedExample()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Starter что не так?

Comment: Как мне заставить QStackedWidget переключаться путём нажатия кнопок? Например, я могу открыть страницу "Управление" нажатием на соответствующую кнопку. QTabWidget не подойдёт.

Comment: @Starter не надо никогда и ничего - заставлять.  Напишите, например вместо `Item 2` - `Управление` и считайте для себя, что это кнопка по нажатию на которую откроется страница "Управление".

Comment: Если я буду использовать этот метод, я не смогу кастомизировать кнопки, в отличие от метода c `QPushButton`. Или смогу?

Comment: @Starter все возможно, что вы имеете ввиду под понятием `кастомизировать` ?

Comment: Нужно придать кнопкам переключения вид, как на картинке

Comment: @Starter все возможно, посмотрите мой ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089514/pyqt-5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-%d0%b2-qlistwidget/1089535#1089535 .

Comment: @Starter   Кстати `QTabWidget` тоже вам подходит посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1094585/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-qlistwidget-%d0%b8-qstackedwidget-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%82/1095146#1095146

Comment: @Starter что не так?