# Не отображется текст в QTabWidget / QTabBar, видно только картинку

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6, qtabwidget, qtabbar

Первый раз пишу приложение на *PyQt6*, опыта разработки приложений нет.
У меня проблема в том, что в **левом боковом меню не отображается текст**. 
Его буквально совершенно нет, смотрите на фото. Сразу скажу, что я пробовал искать различные сайты, где есть это, но там в основном для *PyQt5*. 
Создание меню происходит в методе `DlgMain._create_tabs`, а сама логика описана в `TabWidget`.

---

Что я делал:

1. Пытался менять шрифты.
2. Использовать код отсюда: [Левое меню с использованием Qt Designer и PyQt5](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297730/%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-qt-designer-%D0%B8-python-3-pyqt5)
3. Использовать код отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607298/pyqt-qtabwidget-horizontal-tab-and-horizontal-text-in-qtdesigner
4. Читать документацию.

[image: Приложение с проблемой]

---

Это код главного класса, главный экран:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Ковалев Данил ВКБ22 Вариант 1
"""
import sys
import qdarktheme
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from tabdemo import TabWidget


class DlgMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._init_ui()
        self._create_tabs()

    def _create_tabs(self):
        tabs = TabWidget()
        tabs.create_tabs(4)

        self.setCentralWidget(tabs)

    def _init_ui(self):
        """
        Определение визуальной части интерфейса.
        Здесь добавляются виджеты и свойства приложения.
        """
        self.setWindowTitle("Ковалев Данил ВКБ22")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icons8-окно-приложения-96.png"))
        self.resize(800, 500)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Cantrell', 11))
        self._center()

    def _center(self):
        """
        Метод, который центрует появление приложения по центру экрана.
        """
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """
        Метод, который отвечает за диалоговое окно при закрытии приложения.
        Перегруженный метод класса.
        """
        res = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, "Выход", "Вы точно уверены, что хотите выйти? ")
        event.accept() if res == 16384 else event.ignore()


def main():
    qdarktheme.enable_hi_dpi()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # создаем приложение
    qdarktheme.setup_theme()
    dlg_window = DlgMain()
    dlg_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())  # цикл событий, который отображает виджеты


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Это код, который определяет создание меню:

```
__all__ = ["TabWidget"]

from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore


class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):
    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        s.transpose()
        return s

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.save()

            s = opt.rect.size()
            s.transpose()
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
            opt.rect = r

            c = self.tabRect(i).center()
            painter.translate(c)
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(-c)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)
            painter.restore()


class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setTabBar(TabBar())
        self.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabPosition.West)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Cantrell', 11))

    def create_tabs(self, count):
        for i in range(1, count + 1):
            self.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), QtGui.QIcon("chemistry.png"), f"Лабораторная работа {i}")
```

Comment: Все разрешилось. Я, видимо, плохо настраиваю приложение. Почему-то библиотека, где есть темная тема сломала мне все это. В обычной теме все работает прекрасно.

Comment: C3EQUALZ я специально установил библиотеку `qdarktheme` чтобы проверить, в `PyQt5` все работает как надо, смотрите мой ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не могу проверить ваш код в PyQt6, но в PyQt5 все работает как надо.

Попробуйте еще раз, скопируйте код с моего ответа, поменять импорты и изображения, и запустить. Напишите что у вас получилось и получаете ли вы какие-нибудь сообщения.

А также вам предложу другой вариант того что вы хотите сделать с использованием QListWidget в сочетании с QStackedWidget.  Смотрите вопрос [**Pyqt 5 изменение текущий элемент в QListWidget**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1089514/pyqt-5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-%D0%B2-qlistwidget/1089535#1089535)

```
import sys
import qdarktheme                                      # pip install pyqtdarktheme
'''
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
'''
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


#from tabdemo import TabWidget
class TabBar(QtWidgets.QTabBar):

    def tabSizeHint(self, index):
        s = QtWidgets.QTabBar.tabSizeHint(self, index)
        s.transpose()
        return s

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QtWidgets.QStylePainter(self)
        opt = QtWidgets.QStyleOptionTab()

        for i in range(self.count()):
            self.initStyleOption(opt, i)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabShape, opt)
            painter.save()

            s = opt.rect.size()
            s.transpose()
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), s)
            r.moveCenter(opt.rect.center())
            opt.rect = r

            c = self.tabRect(i).center()
            painter.translate(c)
            painter.rotate(90)
            painter.translate(-c)
            painter.drawControl(QtWidgets.QStyle.ControlElement.CE_TabBarTabLabel, opt)
            painter.restore()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, num_lab):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"Лабораторная работа {num_lab}")
        self.label.setStyleSheet("""
            color: rgb(253, 253, 253); 
            font-size: 24px;
        """)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label,  
            alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        

class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
#        self.setTabBar(TabBar())
        self.setTabBar(TabBar(self))
        
        self.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.TabPosition.West)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Cantrell', 11))

    def create_tabs(self, count):
        for i in range(1, count + 1):
#            self.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), QtGui.QIcon("chemistry.png"), f"Лабораторная работа {i}")
            self.addTab(Widget(i), QtGui.QIcon("Ok.png"), f"Лабораторная работа {i}")
#            self.addTab(QtWidgets.QWidget(), f"Лабораторная работа {i}")


class DlgMain(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self._init_ui()
        self._create_tabs()

    def _create_tabs(self):
        tabs = TabWidget()
        tabs.create_tabs(4)

        self.setCentralWidget(tabs)

    def _init_ui(self):
        """
        Определение визуальной части интерфейса.
        Здесь добавляются виджеты и свойства приложения.
        """
        self.setWindowTitle("Ковалев Данил ВКБ22")
# ------------------------------------> vvvvvv <---------------------------------
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("im.png"))
        self.resize(800, 500)
        self.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Cantrell', 11))
        self._center()

    def _center(self):
        """
        Метод, который центрует появление приложения по центру экрана.
        """
        qr = self.frameGeometry()
        cp = QtGui.QGuiApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry().center()
        qr.moveCenter(cp)
        self.move(qr.topLeft())

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        """
        Метод, который отвечает за диалоговое окно при закрытии приложения.
        Перегруженный метод класса.
        """
        res = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.question(self, 
            "Выход", "Вы точно уверены, что хотите выйти? ")
        event.accept() if res == 16384 else event.ignore()


def main():
    qdarktheme.enable_hi_dpi()
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # создаем приложение
    qdarktheme.setup_theme()
    dlg_window = DlgMain()
    dlg_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())  # цикл событий, который отображает виджеты


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, все работает теперь. Не подскажите ли: существует возможность сделать меню, чтобы оно выдвигалось? Насколько это сложно? Я так понял, что теперь можно взаимодействовать с layout, которое вы описали в классе Widget. Теперь можно в него все добавлять, как я понял.

Comment: @C3EQUALZ пожалуйста. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный и полезный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour Да, меню можно сделать чтобы оно выдвигалось. Да, это может быть сложновато первый раз. Но вам повезло, на этом ресурсе уже были такие вопросы. вам надо только их найти и попробовать применить в своем приложении. Попробуйте, если не будет получатся - зададите новый вопрос.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в вашем классе Widget нельзя ещё нормально добавить элемент. Если я напишу `other = QtWidgets.QLabel(f"Задание на выполнение\n\n\n\nfsdkf")` и потом напишу `self.layout.addWidget(other,
                              alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignHCenter | QtCore.Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignTop)`, то код будет неккоретно отображать новый виджет. Он будет не чуточку ниже Combobox и текста "Лабораторная .", а прям практически по центру. Может я что-то не так делаю?

Comment: @C3EQUALZ если у вас есть другие проблемы - задайте новый вопрос. Приведите код, который демонстрирует проблему и хорошо расскажите что вы хотите сделать, и как-то покажите, что вы хотите получить.